# Как можно оптимизировать код(вузовская задача)

Tags: c, циклы, оптимизация, производительность

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER timerFrequency, timerStart, timerStop;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&timerFrequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&timerStart);

    unsigned long long s, i, N = 1000000000;
    for (s = 0, i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        s += N / i;
        if (i % 10000000 == 0) printf("\rIteration: %I64i", i);
    }

    printf("\ns= %I64i\n", s);


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&timerStop);
    double t = (double)(timerStop.QuadPart - timerStart.QuadPart) / timerFrequency.QuadPart;

    printf("Time is %1f seconds.", t);

    return 0;
}
```

Не совсем понимаю как его можно оптимизировать,сама задача сделать оптимизацию более ,чем на 20%.Данная программа совершает итерации и накапливает значение в переменную S за,чуть более,чем 10 секунд.Нужно ускорить это время до,хотя бы,8 секунд

Comment: Так не годится: `for(unsigned long long i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        printf("\rIteration: %I64i", i*10000000);
    printf("\ns= %I64i\n", 20877697634ull);`? :) Кстати, если всерьез - отключите строку `if(i%...` - и увидите, насколько поднимется производительность...

Comment: Я понимаю,если отключить строку с if ,то повышается производительность в разы,но препод сказал,чтобы считало итерации

Comment: Ну замените `s += N / i;` на 50-100 строк `s += N / i++;` :) Блин, только заметил... А зачем вам N и i - 64-битные?! Замените на обычные int - будет куда быстрее.

Comment: Смотрите, начиная с N/2 + 1 все итерации будут прибавлять к сумме 1. Аналогично, от N/4 + 1 до N/2 к сумме добавится на каждой итерации 2 и т.п. Все эти итерации делать не нужно, вычисляете и складываете. Вот и оптимизация на 3/4 от вашего количества действий. Думаю, если немного "покумекать", то вообще можно вывести формулу и вычислить сумму без циклов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не годится тривиальный способ

```
for(unsigned long long i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) 
    printf("\rIteration: %I64i", i*10000000); 
printf("\ns= %I64i\n", 20877697634ull);
```

и позарез нужно выводить по ходу дела итерации, то главное ускорение - не использовать 64 бита там, где хватит и 32:

```
unsigned long long s;
int i, N = 1000000000;
for (s = 0, i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    s += N / i;
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) printf("\rIteration: %i", i);
}
```

Еще один вариант ускорения - уже поменьше - заменить `%10000000` чем-то красивым в смысле бинарном - например, `%0x800000` - оптимизатор сможет немного ускорить.

Ускорит и разворот цикла типа

```
for (s = 0, i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    s += N / i++;
    s += N / i++;
    ...
    s += N / i++;
    s += N / i;
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) printf("\rIteration: %i", i);
}
```

Только надо подобрать так, чтоб `printf` все же иногда что-то выводил :)

Хорошо бы оптимизировать математику, но тут что-то пока идей нет...